# Lubuntu / LXDE with a weird left margin

Tags: start-menu, desktop-customization, lubuntu, lxde

I'm having an issue with My desktop manager (LXDE, with Lubuntu), Where the shortcut Super + left arrow key was supposed to put the current window against the left side of the screen, but leaves a unexplained margin; in the print, marked in red. Happens in any application. Already did:

lxpanelctl restart && openbox --restart

to try an restart the interface. Rebooted to no avail.

[image]

This started when i was messing with the main menu options. Double checked parameters, but i don't see anything strange. I think those are the initial parameters. Of course, if i resize the window manually, works normally, even the snapping.

[image: panel options]

also, i don't believe there are any funky apps messing the layout

[image: LXDE menu options]

and here are my specs:

```
Distro: Lubuntu
Linux 4.15.0-70-generic x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Codename:   bionic
Model: Asus n71 jq
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 4.15.0-70-generic 
Uptime: 8 mins 
Packages: 3492 
Resolution: 1600x900, 1680x1050 
DE: LXDE 
WM: Openbox 
WM Theme: Onyx 
Theme: Crux [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Lubuntu [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: lxterminal 
CPU: Intel i7 Q 720 (8) @ 1.600GHz 
GPU: AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5730 
Memory: 1960MiB / 7901MiB 

Linux version 4.15.0-70-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-055) 
(gcc version 7.4.0 > (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)) 
#79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 10:36:11 UTC 2019
```

I'm not sure if it was clear, or if u good ppl need more info to help out, so please, ask if needed. Thanks